# Passing command line argument with whitespace in Python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to pass the command line argument with white space in it, but `sys.argv[1].strip()` gives me only first word of the argument

```
import sys, os
docname = sys.argv[1].strip()

 e.g. $ python myscript.py argument with whitespace
```

If I try to debug - docname gives me output as `argument` instead of `argument with whitespace`

I tried to replace the white space with `.replace(" ","%20")` method but that didn't help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Python and everything to do with the shell. The shell has a feature called *[wordsplitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)* that makes each word in your command invocation a separate word, or arg. To pass the result to Python as a single word with spaces in it, you must either escape the spaces, or use quotes.

```
./myscript.py 'argument with whitespace'
./myscript.py argument\ with\ whitespace
```

In other words, by the time your arguments get to Python, wordsplitting has already been done, the unescaped whitespace has been eliminated and `sys.argv` is (basically) a list of words.

Comment: Escaping would be: `./myscript.py argument\ with\ whitespace`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `argv[1:]` instead of `argv[1]`:

```
docname = sys.argv[1:]
```

To print it as a string:

```
' '.join(sys.argv[1:])  # Output: argument with whitespace
```

`sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script itself, and `sys.argv[1:]` is a list of all arguments passed to your script.

**Output:**

```
>>> python myscript.py argument with whitespace
['argument', 'with', 'whitespace']
```

Comment: I know that `strip()` is a `str` method, that's why I am using `sys.argv[1:]`

Comment: sys.argv is a list thus sys.argv[1:] is a slice of that list.

Comment: It is not me who did it.

Comment: @Organis I do not mean you! `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script itself, that's why we use `sys.argv[1:]` to read the rest of options

Answer (score 2):

## Using strings in command line

You can use double quoted string literal in the command line. Like

```
python myscript.py "argument with whitespace"
```

Else of:

```
python myscript.py argument with whitespace
```

## Using backslashes

Here you can use backslashes too:

```
python myscript.py argument\ with\ whitespace\
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with argparse:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file",
                    help="specify the file to be used (enclose in double-quotes if necessary)",
                    type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.file:
    print("The file requested is:", args.file)
```

The results are:

```
$ ./ex_filename.py --help
usage: ex_filename.py [-h] [-f FILE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f FILE, --file FILE  specify the file to be used (enclose in double-quotes
                        if necessary)

$ ./ex_filename.py -f "~/testfiles/file with whitespace.txt"
The file requested is: ~/testfiles/file with whitespace.txt
$
```

Note that the -h / --help comes "free".

Comment: Note that you need to use double-quotes here.  Single-quotes won't work.