# How to insert an *entire* sentence from a shell script into a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, shell

I am using a Python script that receives variables from a shell script to transmit data via an API call, the third variable being the commit message. When I try to use it however, it only prints the first word of the string and stops at the next space. Example:

`"Testing this out"` becomes `"Testing"`.

I want the entire thing to transmit. It is transmitted from a shell script that is the third argument and comes over as `"3=Testing this out"` I have the code currently removing the `3=` part, but the problem described above happens.

This is what I have so far:

The shell script `$1`, `2`, and `3` are prompts taken by a program called appworx as user entered prompts:

```
python3 /RPS_files/script_deployment/Official_Gitlab.py $1 $2 $3
```

The python code:

```
import requests
import string
import json
import sys
from pathlib import Path

url = "hidden for privacy purposes"

headers = {
    "PRIVATE-TOKEN": "hidden for privacy purposes",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

author = sys.argv[1]
author = author.replace("1=","")
filename = "/RPS_files/script_deployment_nz/" + sys.argv[2]
filename = filename.replace("2=","")
commit = sys.argv[3]
commit = commit.replace("3=","")
content = Path(filename).read_text()

sql_substring = ".sql"
loader_substring = ".ctl"
shell_substring = ".sh"

if sql_substring in filename:
    file_path = "New Testing Folder/NZ SQL Folder" + filename

elif loader_substring in filename:
    file_path = "New Testing Folder/NZ Loader Scripts Folder" + filename

elif shell_substring in filename:
    file_path = "New Testing Folder/NZ Shell Scripts" + filename


payload = {
               "id": "9081",
               "branch" : "master",
           "author_name": author,
           "author_email" : "N/A",
           "committer_name": author,
           "committer_email" : "N/A",
               "commit_message": commit,
               "actions": [

                   {
                   "action":"create",
               "file_path": file_path,
               "content": content
                   }
                   ]

               }

verify='/RPS_files/script_deployment/cacert.pem'
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload), verify=verify)

pretty_json = json.loads(response.text)
print(json.dumps(pretty_json, indent=2))
```

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41125488/10987432

Comment: Quote your arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..

I did an easy script to receive data a while ago.

I used the popen function from the os module.

Did it like this:

```
stream = popen("command to run")
data = stream.read()

print(data)
```

---

For me it did the trick to receive the complete shell output

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate all the arguments from number 3 to the end with space like this

```py
commit = " ".join(sys.argv[3:])
```

Or simply you can pass the commit message in quotes

```sh
python pgm.py arg1 arg2 'commit message'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that space is used to separate arguments on the prompt - and that INCLUDES spaces in variables.

The reason is that variables get replaced before the command gets executed, so it's effectively running:

```
python3 /RPS_files/script_deployment/Official_Gitlab.py arg1 arg2 Testing this out
```

As you can see, $3 is just the word "Testing" - the rest is in $4 and $5.

If you quote your variables, the shell knows to treat it as a single argument, which is what you want.  A good habit to get into is to ALWAYS quote your variables unless you explicitly want it treated otherwise - which is almost always never (whenever I do, I leave a comment explaining why, as future is me very likely to quote it).

In this case I would be running:

```
python3 /RPS_files/script_deployment/Official_Gitlab.py "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

Another reason to quote them all - if $1 is empty for any reason, $2 suddenly becomes the first argument, and everything gets shifted forward a place.  If it's in quotes, however, even if it's empty it still gets run as "", so at least the emptiness of gets preserved.

As a bonus, you can use bashes prefix matching feature to remove the leading "3=" if it exists at the same time:

```
python3 /RPS_files/script_deployment/Official_Gitlab.py "${1#1=}" "${2#2=}" "${3#3=}"
```